# CakePHP3 best way to include own php Classes

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I search for that Question a lot and find no really satisfied answer. 
So I want to use cakePHP3 for web-app development. My old Apps I write without a framework, and have a folder structure like this:

```
/config
/views
/classes
...
```

Classes I include with require_once and everthink work fine.

Know. How or where I should put my PHP Classes in Cake structure? Should I put my Classes into the Vendor folder and get it with `require_once(ROOT .DS. "vendor" . DS  . "CLASS" . DS . "myClass.php");`

What is the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cake uses `composer` ([psr-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)) to autoload classes so there is no need to do `require`.  You can make a folder under `src` directory.Lets say your folder name is `CustomClasses`. Make a new class named `TestClass.php` in this folder.

```
namespace App\CustomClasses;
class TestClass
{
    public function test()
    {
        echo "Ok";
    }
}`
```

From your controller method call your custom class with namespace.

```
 $class = new \App\CustomClasses\TestClass();
 echo $class->test();
```

Comment: Tested it and it works fine. Think that this is the better solution. Thx Kamran